# tkinter grid manager behaviour

Tags: python, tkinter, grid

So i want to build an assistant off sorts which will do auto backs ups etc and instead of using .place i would like a proper grid to place widgets.
I cannot find a good example of the grid manager.

```
self.parent = tk.Frame(window, bg = BLACK)        
username_label = ttk.Label(self.parent, text = "Username")
password_label = ttk.Label(self.parent, text = "Password")

self.parent.grid(column = 0, row = 0)
username_label.grid(column = 1, row = 1)
password_label.grid(column = 2, row = 2)

self.parent.grid_columnconfigure(0, weight = 1)
```

I want...

```
               Button
               Button
Label Entry    Button
Label Entry    Button
               Button
```

I don't understand how i can position them like this as i want a blank space above the labels. so far grid has only let me place things next to each other.

Honestly, any websites or code examples would be greatly appreciated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So, if you want blank space above the label, you can either set `pady` as an argument to the `grid` method or simply put them in the corresponding row. Consider the following example:

```
import tkinter as tk
root=tk.Tk()

for i in range(6):
    tk.Button(root,text='Button %d'%i).grid(row=i,column=1)
tk.Label(root,text='Label 0').grid(row=2,column=0,pady=20)
tk.Label(root,text='Label 1').grid(row=3,column=0)

root.mainloop()
```

Notice the effect of the `pady` argument. Also, if you only want a blank line above the `Label`, you can try to put a blank `Label` in the row above. E.g.:

```
import tkinter as tk
root=tk.Tk()

for i in range(6):
    tk.Button(root,text='Button %d'%i).grid(row=i,column=1)
tk.Label(root,text='Label 0').grid(row=2,column=0,pady=20)
tk.Label(root,text='Label 1').grid(row=3,column=0)
tk.Label(root,text='').grid(row=6)
tk.Label(root,text='This is a Label with a blank row above').grid(row=7,columnspan=2)
root.mainloop()
```

You can refer to [effbot](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/grid.htm) for more information, which is the blog of tkinter's developer.

Comment: Absolute legend! Thank you very much!